# Transpose A List And Turn It Into A Data Frame in R

Tags: r, list, web-scraping, transpose

I am having a bit of an issue turning a list into a tidy data frame.

I am scraping data from yahoo finance and turning it into a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(quantmod)

ticker = "SPY"
spydf = read_html("https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY&.tsrc=fin-srch") %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[2] %>% html_table(fill = T)
print(spydf)
[[1]]
                   X1         X2
1          Net Assets    268.03B
2                 NAV     300.76
3      PE Ratio (TTM)        N/A
4               Yield      1.85%
5          YTD Return     21.76%
6   Beta (3Y Monthly)       1.00
7 Expense Ratio (net)      0.09%
8      Inception Date 1993-01-22

class(spydf)
"list"
```

I would like the final product to be the transpose of the above. Where X1 are the headers and X2 are the columns.

```
#Something like this.
 Net_Assets    NAV Yield Beta Expense_Ratio  ....
1     286.03 300.76  1.85    1          0.09  ...
```

Here is what I have tried and it does not seem to work

```
spy = read_html("https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY&.tsrc=fin-srch") %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[2] %>% html_table(fill = T) %>% as.data.frame() 
spy = t(spy) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(spy) = spy[1,]
spy = spy[-1,]

print(spy)
c(X1 = 2) c(X1 = 2) c(X1 = 2) c(X1 = 2) c(X1 = 2) c(X1 = 2)
X2   268.03B    300.76       N/A     1.85%    21.76%      1.00
   c(X1 = 2)  c(X1 = 2)
X2     0.09% 1993-01-22
```

I have tried others but I will try and keep this clean.

Comment: Don't bother with the transpose operations.  Just do this after the read_html step: `spy %>% spread(X1, X2)`

Comment: worked great. Thanks David.  I had to add a  %>% .[[1]] %>% spread(X1,X2) and it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format